# Iterating over columns in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a simple VBA script that opens all of the .xls files in a given folder, and copies Column A. My desire is to paste that information into a unique column of my workbook. I can't seem to iterate over columns very easily, so in the loop below I am just pasting everything into the same column. I just can't figure out how to update which column I want to paste into. If I was iterating over rows it would be simple it would be Range("A"&LastRow), but columns seem to be trickier. In the loop below everything gets pasted into Column A of the destination workbook (variable wkbDest).

```
Dim wkbDest As Workbook
Dim wkbSource As Workbook 'Source workbooks
Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
Const strPath As String = "C:\SecretPath\"
Const sheetName As String = "MacroResults"
Const xlsPattern As String = "*.xls"
ChDir strPath
strExtension = Dir(xlsPattern)
Dim lastColumn As Long 'variable that will be the counter to iterate over the columns
lastColumn = 0
wkbDest.Sheets(sheetName).Cells.Clear
wkbDest.Sheets(sheetName).Range("A1").Value = "Extraction Results"
Do While strExtension <> ""
    Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension)
    With wkbSource
    lastColumn = lastColumn + 1
    wkbSource.Sheets("Test_1").Columns("A:A").Copy
```

I have tried `wkbDest.Sheets(sheetName).Range("A1").OffSet(0,lastColumn).PasteSpecial` and instead of Range `Columns(lastColumn)`, but nothing seems to work.

```
    wkbDest.Sheets(sheetName).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .Close savechanges:=True
    End With
    strExtension = Dir()
Loop
```

Comment: You can refer to a column by its number. So try something like `wkbDest.Sheets(sheetName).Columns(lastColumn+1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` where `lastColumn` is the last used column in `wkbDest.Sheets(sheetName)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your code, replacing the paste line.

```
' convert the lastColumn into its letter, and then use it
Dim vArr as Variant, Col_Letter as string
vArr = Split(Cells(1, lastColumn ).Address(True, False), "$")
Col_Letter = vArr(0)

wkbDest.Sheets(sheetName).Range(Col_Letter & "1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```